# Find mean of first 9 numbers then the next 9 numbers and so on from for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `for` loop that gives me the following output.

```
0.53125
0.4375
0.546875
0.578125
0.75
0.734375
0.640625
0.53125
0.515625
0.828125
0.5
0.484375
0.59375
0.59375
0.734375
0.71875
0.609375
0.484375
.
.
.
```

How do I find the mean of the first 9 values, the next 9 values and so on and store them into a list like `[0.58,0.20,...]`? I have tried a lot of things but the values seem to be incorrect. What is the correct way of doing this?

What I did:

```
matchedRatioList = []
matchedRatio = 0
i = 0
for feature in range(90):
    featureToCompare = featuresList[feature]
    number = labelsList[feature]
    match = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,featureToCompare,imagePixList)
    matchingRatio = match.ratio()
    print(matchingRatio)
    matchedRatio += matchingRatio
    if i == 8:
        matchedRatioList.append(matchedRatio / 9)
        i = 0
        matchedRatio = 0
    i += 1
```

Comment: *I have tried a lot of things* - Please show them, we might be able to help you fix them.

Comment: @thefourtheye ok, sure

Comment: Decompose your problem in to smaller parts. To take the means of groups of 9, you need to know how to make groups of 9 and how to take means of groups. I suppose in this case it's the former that gives you problems, so you're asking about forming groups and taking means is irrelevant. Luckily how to group lists into many evenly sized smaller lists has been asked many times.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien I am having problems with splitting them into groups of 9 and then finding their means. I have been coding from the morning, my brain is lagging. Any idea of how I could do it?

Comment: Are you getting wrong result?

Comment: If you successfully grouped your input into groups of 9 values, you wouldn't have a problem finding the means of those groups. So focus on the grouping before thinking about what to do with those groups.

Comment: @thefourtheye yup wrong values in the output list.

Comment: Note that you're doing `i=0` in the `if` block and then `i+=1` immediately after.

Comment: @muru Is there another way to group them into groups of 9?

Comment: What @muru is trying to point out is that you're counting 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. You should not increase `i` when you just set it to `0`, so you're missing an `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the list of numbers you can calculate the average of each group of 9 numbers using list comprehensions:

```
from statistics import mean

numbers = [0.53125, 0.4375, 0.546875, 0.578125, 0.75, 0.734375, 0.640625,
           0.53125, 0.515625, 0.828125, 0.5, 0.484375, 0.59375, 0.59375, 
           0.734375, 0.71875, 0.609375, 0.484375]

group_len = 9
matched_ratios = [mean(group) for group in [numbers[i:i+group_len] 
                  for i in range(0, len(numbers), group_len)]]
print(matched_ratios)
# [0.5850694444444444, 0.6163194444444444]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is close. Start with `i = 1` and check for `i == 9`

```
matchedRatioList = []
matchedRatio = 0
i = 1   # change here
for feature in range(90):
    ...
    matchedRatio += matchingRatio
    if i == 9:  # change here
        matchedRatioList.append(matchedRatio / 9)
        i = 0
        matchedRatio = 0
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you have tried so far, but I can present you with one solution to the problem.

Save all values in your for-loop to a buffer array. Use an if-statement with `iterator % 9 == 0` inside your for-loop, which will make some portion of code execute only every 9 values.

Inside the if-statement you can write the mean value of your buffer array to a different output array. Reset your buffer array inside this if-statement as well, then this process is repeated and should behave in the way you want.

Comment: But value % 9 will exclude multiple of 9 values won't they?

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake, you should use the iterator of your for-loop in stead of the value!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
r = []
for b in a:
    c += b
    if i == 8:
        c = c/9
        r.append(c)
        c = 0
        i = 0
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mean function from the statistics module of Python.

```
import statistics
# Sample Values list I created.
values_list = list()
for i in range(1,82):
    values_list.append(i)
mean_list = list()
for i in range(0, len(values_list), 9):
    mean_list.append(statistics.mean(values_list[i:i+9]))
for i in mean_list:
    print(i)
```

This is the simplest way in which you can do it.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean

Answer (score 0):

since nobody used reduce so far :)

```
import functools
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
m = []
for i in range(9,len(l), 9):
    m.append(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l[i-9:i])/9)
print(m)
```

Comment: it is adding `0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8 = 36, 36 / 9 = 4`

Comment: then adds 9 to i which becomes 18, then `9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17 = 117, 117/9 = 13` and 18 is left off because it is only adding full 9 elements chunks

Answer (score 0):

One-line solution given loop output in `numbers`:

```
[float(sum(a))/len(a) for a in zip(*[iter(numbers)]*9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting ideas from the other answers together, this could be the whole program:

```
from statistics import mean

matching_ratios = (difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, feature, imagePixList).ratio()
                   for feature in featuresList[:90])
matchedRatioList = [mean(group) for group in zip(*[matching_ratios] * 9)]
```